# Return Parameterized type in Sublclasss

Tags: java

I have a class with a method that returns a List with that class as the parameter type. I am trying to extend that class, and then override the method that returns that List and have the List parameterized to the subclass. The return type of the subclass is incompatible with the return type of the superclass.

```
public interface GenericReturnTypeList {

    public <T> List<T> getNames();
}

class FirstName implements GenericReturnTypeList{
    String fName;

    public List<FirstName> getNames(){
        return null;
    }
}

class FullName extends FirstName{
    String lName;

    public List<FullName> getNames(){

    }
}
```

Is there a different way to accomplish the same thing? thanks

Comment: @Hovercraft I would like to be able to instatiate a GenericReturnListType variable as either FirstName or FullName. Following that I would like to be able to call getNames(), and return either a list of firstNames, or a list of fullNames

Comment: The issue was that the way you formatted your posted code, using the `<pre>` tags, the generic parameters were not visible. I reformated your post so that code was properly formatted as code, and the generic parameters became visible, making your question much more understandable.

Comment: @Hovercraft thanks, my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using wildcards and casting the returned List is how I ended up getting it to work. Not sure if this is the best practice:

```
public interface GenericReturnTypeList{

    public List<?> getNames();
}

class FirstName implements GenericReturnTypeList{
    String fName;

    public List<?> getNames(){
        return null;
    }
}

class FullName extends FirstName{
    String lName;

    public List<?> getNames(){
        return null;
    }

}

class NameGetter {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        GenericReturnTypeList firstN = new FirstName();
        List<FirstName> firstNList = (List<FirstName>) firstN.getNames();

        GenericReturnTypeList fullN = new FullName();
        List<FullName> fnList = (List<FullName>)fullN.getNames();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change your interface to

```
public interface GenericListReturn {
    public List<?> getNames();
}
```

This will allow implementing methods to return any kind of list, but the caller will not know what kind of list he gets. Note that this method can be implemented with a covariant return type:

```
public class FirstName implements GenericListReturn {
    @Override public List<FirstName> getNames();
}
```

**Alternative**

Alternatively, you could parametrize your interface:

```
public interface GenericReturnTypeList<E> {
    public List<E> getNames();
}
```

so implementors can choose what type to return, and callers can know what kind of list they get by constraining that type parameter.

Because the type is self-referential, this gets rather unwieldly, though:

```
public class FirstName<F extends FirstName<F>> implements GenericReturnTypeList<F> {
    @Override public List<F> getNames();
}

public class FullName extends FirstName<FullName> {
    @Override public List<FullName> getNames();
}
```

which is probably not worth it in this case.

Comment: The problem is that the subclass return type is not the same as superclass return type. Neither of these suggestions resolves the issue.

Comment: in this case he/she must implement the declared interface nut he/she wants to extends the class that implements the interface . Java does not support  declaration site variance. so he must change the hierarchy

Comment: @ribaker : what you are asking is called declaration-site variance and Java does not support that.So you need to check your hirarchy

Comment: @rlbaker You can also Google about covriance and contravariance that will give you more insight

Comment: Apparently the indended signatures for the subclass weren't clear, I have added them for clarity. And no, Java does not have declaration-site variance. Instead, it has usage-site variance through wildcard types (c.f. my first suggestion).